getting maximum update depth exceeded error when trying to conditional render
Getting maximum update depth exceeded error when trying to conditional render a section inside render.
I have a component in which i need to render sections like below
export class Sections extends React.Component {
    renderSections() {
        switch(sectionId) {
            case section1:
                return <section1 />
            case section2:
                return <section2 />
            default:
        }
    }

    render(){
        this.renderSections();
    }
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
        renderSection2: formValueSelector(props.formName)(state, 'a'),
        array1: array1 || []
    }  
}

I need to render section2 only when renderSection2 is true and array1.length === 1.
I tried to do something like below:
case section2:
    if(renderSection2 && array1.length === 1) {
        return <section2 />
    }
    return null; 

But, Im getting maximum update depth exceeded error. Couldn't figure out what's causing the issue. Can someone help on How to solve the issue ?
I cannot change the switch statement to if else's as I have many cases in switch. Any insights will be helpful. Thank you

Can you provide a Minimum Reproducible Example?
